# Could Antimatter be used to make antigravity devices?

Tags: science-based, physics

Line of thought here:

One of matter's properties is mass, and mass leads to gravity

Antimatter has negative mass, thus, antimatter could have a affect against gravity, either by canceling it out or acting reverse of it (kinda like putting the north poles of two magnets together)

Does this make any sense and/or fall in line with our current scientific understanding of antimatter?

Comment: Please note that science based and science fiction tags are mutually exclusive

Comment: Antimatter isn't an actual thing, it is an explanation to the origin of extra forces on our calculations that we can't explain otherwise, it can't have negative mass because it is an explanation for excessive mass. It can't be used for anything because it is not an actual thing

Comment: @TurtleTail You may be confusing Antimatter with Dark Matter, from what you're saying? Antimatter is an actual thing that has been observed in the lab.

Comment: @Onyz I was, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: And clouds of Dark Matter have actually been observed due to the gravitational lensing it causes.  We don't know everything there is to know about it, but it appears to exhibit a positive gravitational force without having any electromagnetic properties like normal matter.  So it also does not exhibit anti-gravity.  Dark Energy on the other hand has not be observed and could potentially be a source of anti-gravity.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Not the place for a debate, but indirect observation of gravitational lensing is not necessarily proof either way. Personally I think the fact that dark matter is supposed to be so common and yet there is seemingly none on Earth, or our solar system, or really anywhere nearby, is an indicator that there is yet more for us to understand about the 'bandaid' fix that is Dark Matter. Obviously there's a lot to say about this in support of Dark Matter too, though, and it's not worth discussing here. Better to agree to disagree.

Comment: The effect of gravity on antimatter has not been directly observed, though it is strongly expected that it will be similar to normal matter. Also, antimatter has positive mass since it requires energy to produce.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter

Comment: @Onyz Galactic collisions when combined with gravitational lensing prove its existence. There are plenty of online articles about it like this, https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2020/01/20/this-is-how-galaxy-cluster-collisions-prove-the-existence-of-dark-matter/?sh=219f10e35b23 . My daughter has a book called "We have no Idea" that has a really accurate but also easy to understand explanation of what is and is not actually known about dark matter.  Turns out its not nearly as mysterious as SciFi likes to make it sound.

Comment: I don't think this Q deserves all the downvotes it has. Whether antimatter exhibited "antigravity" (positive inertial mass, negative gravitational mass) was a serious topic of research. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139545/has-the-gravitational-interaction-of-antimatter-ever-been-examined-experimentall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use antimatter annihilation to create exotic matter

What you're looking for is something with negative mass. Negative mass presumably creates negative gravity.

All the matter we know about has positive mass. But theory at least makes room for the possibility of matter which has negative mass. "Exotic matter" is a term usually applied to anything that fits that description.

As far as I'm aware, there is zero evidence that anything like that exists, or has ever existed. But that doesn't mean it *couldn't* exist, either naturally occurring but only in remote places, or something that can only be created in laboratory conditions.

I imagine that creating and maintaining exotic matter will probably require a lot of energy. After all, it it were easy to create, natural conditions would probably result in plenty of the stuff.

Antimatter doesn't have negative mass, but it can be used as part of an energy generating scheme. So, you can use antimatter indirectly to create antigravity.

Answer (score 9):

No.

Antimatter doesn't have negative mass.

Negative mass is thought to have negative gravity, though. Which leads to neat results; if you have a block of negative mass and one of positive mass, the negative gets attracted to the positive, but the positive gets repelled by the negative, so both start to accellerate infinitely!

Negative mass is purely hypothetical at the moment, though, while antimatter is real.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, but not in the way you suppose**

You could use the antimatter to transport a large amount of energy. Use the annihilation energy of matter-antimatter to feed your propulsion and off you go.

As long as your acceleration is say 1G or more, there will be "artificial gravity" inside the ship.

Comment: He's asking for anti-gravity, not artificial gravity.

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe?

There are a number of [on-going experiments](https://home.cern/news/news/experiments/new-antimatter-gravity-experiments-begin-cern) to determine the gravitational interaction of antimatter. (Whether antimatter has *positive* "inertial" yet *negative* "gravitational" mass.) Here's [more on that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139545/has-the-gravitational-interaction-of-antimatter-ever-been-examined-experimentall).

We're *pretty sure* it's positive all the way around (much of what we understand about physics would break otherwise). It most likely isn't negative all the way around, because negative inertial mass is problematic to say the least.

In short: no, it doesn't have negative mass in the way you think, but it *may* have antigravity still (by virtue of us not knowing with 100% certainty its gravitational mass).